# What is the meaning of argument in Bilinear distortion in Imagick

Tags: php, image, imagick

I was referring example of [Imagick::distortImage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.distortimage.php)

Now look at Example 1 which generates following image

[image]

I got confused while looking at below part of code.

```
/* Control points for the distortion */
$controlPoints = array( 10, 10, 
                        10, 5,

                        10, $im->getImageHeight() - 20,
                        10, $im->getImageHeight() - 5,

                        $im->getImageWidth() - 10, 10,
                        $im->getImageWidth() - 10, 20,

                        $im->getImageWidth() - 10, $im->getImageHeight() - 10,
                        $im->getImageWidth() - 10, $im->getImageHeight() - 30);
```

Now can anybody tell me what this 16 points exactly means ?

Comment: /* Control points for the distortion */
What don't you understand?

Comment: meaning of each position and their importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control point arguments are helpfully organised into this layout:

```
x1  , y1  ,
x1' , y1' ,

x2  , y2  ,
x2' , y2' ,

x3  , y3  ,
x3' , y3' ,

x4  , y4  ,
x4' , y4'
```

For each set of coordinates, `x_` and `y_` are the source points, and `x_'` and `y_'` are the targets.

So it's taking the top-left corner and moving it up a bit, the bottom-left is being moved down, the top-right is being moved down and the bottom-right is being moved up, producing the perspective result.

Comment: shouldn't top left corner start with 0,0 ?? @Niet the Dark Absol

Comment: Yes, but it's not grabbing the very top-left-most pixel.

Comment: Always x_ and y_ should be the corner points right ?? here they have given 10,10 as top left (x1,y1). same in for remaining x_ and y_, so I am confused. correct me if I am wrong, because I am new bee in image processing..

Comment: No, they can be any points you want. It's just that, in this case, it's most helpful to move the corners.